# MySQL Shell SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: command-line, shell, mysql

I'm trying to follow this guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup-installation.html

> 2. Connect to the MySQL server using the mysql command-line client with the following command:
>
>    shell> mysql -u root -p

I typed this exact command into the MySQL shell, and it does not work, it gives the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier":

[image: MySQL Shell SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier]

I also tried just typing `mysql` and it prints out `<mysql>`, not very helpful.

I also tried skipping the first step and typing `SOURCE C:/temp/world.sql;` (including by replacing that path with the actual path to my `world.sql`) and it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier".

I also tried typing `SOURCE` by itself and it says "ReferenceError: SOURCE is not defined".

I'm quite confused, I have no idea what I'm missing, I think I'm following the guide correctly. I'm using MySQL 8.0.21.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645402/mysql-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier I too had this problem and I found the answer here!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same problem with the normal mysql client several years ago.

The solution then was to use `-uroot` (note the missing space character between the option and the user name). You could also try `--user=root`.

Please don't flame me if this does lead nowhere. With my current installation, I can't reproduce the problem; plus, I don't use MySQL shell. However, I believe chances are good that it works with one of the above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

On this specific shell u have to enter the command: `\connect roo@localhost:3306` if u want to connect as the admin
and to use SQL command, u have to proceed like this for example `\sql use mysql` to selct mysql database. So every SQL commands has to begin by **\sql**

mysql guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html